# How to type floating point numbers in Apple Numbers in Persian?

Tags: macos, keyboard, numbers, language, internationalization

When I want to insert a floating number in Apple Numbers 3.6.1 in OS X 10.10.5 while my primary preferred language in `Language & Region` is Persian(فارسی), the number is interpreted as a string value.

[image]

In these screenshots the right cell has the formula of `B2 ÷ 2` while `B2` is the left cell. I typed `۱.۲۳` (that is `1.23` in Persian) in `B2` with Persian keyboard layout and an error is occurred.

[image]

The result is the same when i type the number with English keyboard layout.

[image]

How can i enter a floating point number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in Persian language the floating point sign is represented with `,`. So the problem can be solved by entering the number as `۱,۲۳` or `1,23`.

In the first form when you want to enter the floating point sign, switch the keyboard layout to English then insert ‍`,` and then switch it back to Persian and insert the remaining fraction part.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried it with "/"? Because the actual decimal separator in Persian is slash, not a dot, not a comma.